# Things to be blit only inside a polygon (Pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Is it possible to have red circles to only appear inside a polygon. For a rectangle, you can determine the height and width.

I'm planning to make like a virus simulator, and that there are red circles that only appear only inside the countries. But the countries aren't rectangles, but polygons/images.

I was wondering if it was possible to have only circles to be blit inside a polygon or image. 
Thanks

Comment: I dont think so. Polygon rect classes to exist in other frameworks, but not sdl and therefore pygame.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, specifically what you mean by  _"have only circles to be blit inside a polygon"._ Where and what you decide to blit is up to you. So if you decide you only want to blit your circles in places where you have blit polygons, I don't see what could cause problems. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I want circles to appear on the screen at random positions, but only appears within a polygon.

Comment: Please add more details about the game and show us some code. How do you create the polygons? Maybe an image (or animated gif) would make the question clearer.

Comment: Like a map, I found an image online, but I can redraw it as a polygon easily. It is kind of like a virus simulator, but the viruses will not be in the water, I will somehow need to set restrictions for the dots to appear only within the countries. The red dots represent infected people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a map as an image, and you want to determine if a random point is on land or not. What you need for that is an image redrawn to have only black and white pixels. You can then use Pygame's Surface.get_at() command to see what color the pixel there is, and make a decision based on that.

Alternately, let's say you have a map as a bunch of polygons, and you want to determine if a random point is on land or not. The logic there is called ray tracing, and is explained better over here: [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon)

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib for that. A very simple example (Give values to the vertices of the square):

```
  from matplotlib.path import Path

  verts = [
             left_bottom,
             left_top,
             right_top,
             right_bottom,
             (0, 0),
            ]

    codes = [
             Path.MOVETO,
             Path.LINETO,
             Path.LINETO,
             Path.LINETO,
             Path.CLOSEPOLY,
             ]

    path = Path(verts, codes)

   if path.contains_point((x, y)):
       print("True")
```